# Undefined value when send data from python to aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a problem when send data from client that wrote by python to aws lambda. After that AWS Lambda send it to slack. Under is my code, I want to display "Message sent by raspi 1" but it displayed "Message sent by raspi undefined" in slack message.

Python file:

```
 import requests
 import json
 url = 'https://.....execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/product/events'
 data1 = json.dumps({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
 x = requests.post(url, data = data1)
```

Lambda fuction:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var responseBody = {
    "key3": "value3",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key1": "value1"
};

var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "my_header": "my_value"
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify(responseBody),
    "isBase64Encoded": false
};
const payload = JSON.stringify({
    text: `Message sent by raspi ${event.body.a}`,
});

const options = {
   hostname: "hooks.slack.com",
   method: "POST",
   path: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/TPA2SP0GH/....",
};

const req = https.request(options,
  (res) => res.on("data", () => callback(null, response)))
  req.on("error", (error) => callback(JSON.stringify(error)));
  req.write(payload);
  req.end();
```

};

Comment: ${event.a} is undefined, too :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `event.body` is a json string. you need to parse it before use it.

here:

```
const parsedBody = JSON.parse(event.body);
const payload = JSON.stringify({
  text: `Message sent by raspi ${parsedBody.a}`,
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it with `${event['a']}`. It is still a dictionary, not yet converted to an object.

Comment: it is still undefined :((

Comment: you can debug this by adding a line: var eventString = JSON.stringify(event);  before and change it to `Message sent by raspi ${eventString}` and see what you get.

Comment: Here is JSON.stringify(event): {..... "body": "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": 2}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false}

Comment: Try : `Message sent by raspi ${event['body']['a']}`

Comment: Still undefined :(((